# A stored procedure in a try/catch using transactions

Tags: sql-server, transactions, try-catch

How would I put this SQL Server statement

```
USE OnlineStore
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.spInsertNewProduct
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Product (Name, Size, SalePrice, Category, Department, Location, Description, ProductCondition, SKU, Colors, LastOrderDate, InventoryQuantity, AverageRating)
    VALUES ('King Arthur: Legend of the Sword (Blu-Ray)', 
            '5 3/8” wide x 6 3/4” tall and 1/2” thick', 24.99, 
            'Blu-Ray', 'Movies', 'Ontario', 
            'Blu-Ray of King Arthur: Legend of the Sword', 'New', '324510', 
            'Blue', '2017-8-3', 17, 86)
END
```

in a try/catch using transactions?

Comment: Why? What do you hope to accomplish by wrapping a single statement in a transaction? A single statement is atomic - either it is successful and the rows are added or it fails and the table remains unchanged. Did you give the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql) a look? And try [Erland's discussion](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) which is likely to be a bit too much at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SMor has advised in the comments, there is not really any point in doing that for the insert, it either goes in or it does not, so in effect, there is nothing to roll back. But, should you wish to implement a try/catch, the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql) would be:

```
USE OnlineStore
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.spInsertNewProduct
AS
BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRAN
            INSERT INTO Product (Name, Size, SalePrice, Category, Department, Location, [Description], ProductCondition, SKU, Colors, LastOrderDate, InventoryQuantity, AverageRating)
            VALUES ('King Arthur: Legend of the Sword (Blu-Ray)', 
                    '5 3/8” wide x 6 3/4” tall and 1/2” thick', 24.99, 
                    'Blu-Ray', 'Movies', 'Ontario', 
                    'Blu-Ray of King Arthur: Legend of the Sword', 'New', '324510', 
                    'Blue', '2017-8-3', 17, 86)
            COMMIT TRAN
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRAN
        END CATCH
END
```